# repaint() fails to work

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, repaint

I wanted to draw an image on my panel based on the data I receive from another thread. I am  sure the data and consequent pixel array works well, but the repaint() would never work. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong here?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

/** Create an image from a pixel array. **/
public class PicturePlaza extends JApplet
{
  ImagePanel fImagePanel;
  ReadCom   readComPort;
  Thread readPortThread;

  public void init () {
    // initiate the read port thread so that it can receive data
     readComPort = new ReadCom();
     readPortThread = new Thread(readComPort,"ReadCom");
     readPortThread.start();

     Container content_pane = getContentPane ();
     fImagePanel = new ImagePanel ();
     content_pane.add (fImagePanel);  

  } 

  // Tell the panel to create and display the image, if pixel data is ready.
  public void start () {
      while(true){
          if(readComPort.newPic){
              fImagePanel.go();
          }
          try {
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
  }


/** Create an image from a pixel array. **/
  class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
      Image fImage;
      int fWidth = ReadCom.row, fHeight = ReadCom.col;      

      void go() {         
                    //update the image if newPic flag is set to true                
                    fImage = createImage (new MemoryImageSource (fWidth, fHeight, ReadCom.fpixel, 0, fWidth));
                    repaint();
                    readComPort.newPic = false; //disable the flag, indicating the image pixel has been used                                                            
      } 

      /** Paint the image on the panel. **/
      public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent (g);       
        g.drawImage (fImage, 0, 0, this );  
      } 
  } 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `Thread.sleep(4000);`  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling
`Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.
See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your instant response. But if I simply remove the statement Thread.sleep(4000), it fails to work as well. What is the reason for that?

Comment: If you simply read the links I provided, and implement the recommendations, what happens?

Comment: It worked! But I was still not quite clear about the mechanism behind. If i remove the Thread.sleep(4000) statement, which statement could possibly lead to the freezing of EDT? Could you kindly enlighten me on this?

Comment: The earlier links can explain better than I can in a comment what is happening.  Also, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (posted by you) can encourage people to look closely into, and evaluate the code.  As it is, you are effectively asking why classes not shown might block the progress of the included classes.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little note on `repaint()`.  `repaint()` schedules a repaint of the screen, it won't always do it immediately in my experience.  I found the best solution is to directly call `paint()` yourself.

```
Graphics g;
g = getGraphics();
paint(g);
```

I put this as a new function to call in my code when I wanted it to paint immediately.  Also this will not erase the previous graphics on the screen, you will have to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try `repaint();` and then `validate();` in your Applet (`PicturePlaza`).